# How to change primeng dropdown value/option if url changes

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I am very new to Primeng and Angular, Can you help me with this please:

How to change my param in URL using Primeng *drop-down* in Angular: (ex. shop1 in URL to shop2) `http://localhost:4200/#/shops/shop1/dashboard` and vice versa if I change URL so it must change the value of drop-down as well.

```
 <p-dropdown [options]="clientShops" [(ngModel)]="selectedShop" optionLabel="name" (onChange)="onChange($event)"></p-dropdown>
```

My `OnChange($event)` function returns `{shopId: 'shop2', name: 'Shop 2'}` in component How to get shopId from event?:

```
   onChange(event: any) {    
// How to get shopId from event?
            let shopId = ""; 
           this.router.navigate([`/shops/${shopId}/dashboard`]);
            console.log('event :' + event);
            console.log(event.value);
        }
```

Comment: what's the URL of the component where this dropdown is being used ? http://localhost:4200/#/shops ?

Comment: Component URL is shops/:id/dashboard and The dropdown is present in child component (Top Bar of the dashboard).

Answer (score 1):

```js
        // import 
        import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";

        // in your constructor
        constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,private router: Router) {}

        // on changing the dropdown value
        onDropdownChange(event: any) {
        this.router.navigate(['../../', + event.shopId + '/dashboard'],{relativeTo: this.route});
        }
```

Comment: May I know what is ../../ for here? and I am not getting selected value from primeng dropdown because it only returns {shopId: 'shop2', name: 'Shop 2'} from (onChange)=onChange($event). How to get shopId from return object.

Comment: Since your route ends at "shops/shop1/dashboard", you need to go back 2 levels to change route as per your requirement without reloading, ["../../"] will take you 2 steps back in your current router path, i.e to "shops/", and then you navigate to proper route.

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: event.shopId shows undefined.